# R - stop write.xlsx() from making column names syntactically valid

Tags: r, excel, export

I do have a specific question regarding the `write.xlsx()` function of the `xlsx` package in R.

I do have a matrix containing outputs of panel data regressions. For convenience I do want to export these outputs to a .xlsx file to include it in a Word document. However, when I do export the matrix via `write.xlsx` the column names are automatically edited to the syntactically valid style with no symbols other than points, letters and numbers. So, the column vector of the matrix

`table_columns <- c("Estimate (All periods)", "", "s.e. (All periods)", "Estimate (Periods 0 & 1)", "", "s.e. (Periods 0 & 1)")`

(`""` are empty column names because these columns contain star indicators for p-values)
becomes

`Estimate..All.periods.|V2|s.e...All.periods.|Estimate..Periods.0...1.|V5|s.e...Periods.0...1.`

Is there a way to suppress this reformatting such that I do not need to edit the .xlsx file after output?

***-Edit-*** to make things easier to understand:

I do have a vector `table_rows` with 
`c("All periods", "  Std. error (All periods)", "Periods 0 & 1", "  Std. error (Periods 0 & 1)")`
and a vector `table_columns` with `c("(1) 1AM - 6AM", "", "(2) 6AM - 10AM", "", "(3) 10AM - 6PM", "", "(4) 6PM - 10PM", "", "(5) 10PM - 1AM", "", "(6) Daily", "")`

These are used to set the dimnames of the matrix `table`
 with `matrix(c(table_1, table_1p, table_2, table_2p, table_3, table_3p, table_4, table_4p, table_5, table_5p, table_6, table_6p), 4, 12, dimnames = list(table4_rows, table4_columns))`

where `table_odd` and `table_oddp` denote the column vectors containing estimantes and their p-level indicators and `table_even` the standard errors in parantheses. All vectors are of type `chr`

I do run `write.xlsx(table, paste0(getwd(), "/results.xlsx"), sheetName = "Results")` to convert the matrix to .xlsx

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). How exactly are you calling `write.xlsx`? How exactly is the data.frame you are trying to write formatted. What are you doing with the `table_columns` vector?

Comment: I don't have `xlsx` installed so I haven't verified, but my guess is this: you call `write.xlsx` on a `matrix` object. Then it is internally converted to a `data.frame` (see [lines 46 and 47 here](https://github.com/cran/xlsx/blob/master/R/write.xlsx.R)), which runs `make.names()` on your column names. I bet if you pass `write.xlsx` an object that is *already* a `data.frame` with the column names as you want them, that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert the matrix to a data frame before you pass it wo `write.xlsx`. Otherwise `write.xlsx` will do the job with defaul arguments. However, you need to set `check.names=F` and `fix.empty.names=F` to disable syntax checking and replacing empty column names.

Here's a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) - please post future questions like this:

```
library(xlsx)
table_rows <- c("All periods", "  Std. error (All periods)", "Periods 0 & 1", "  Std. error (Periods 0 & 1)") 
table_columns <- c("(1) 1AM - 6AM", "", "(2) 6AM - 10AM", "", "(3) 10AM - 6PM", "", "(4) 6PM - 10PM", "", "(5) 10PM - 1AM", "", "(6) Daily", "")
m <- matrix(seq_len(4*12), 4, 12, dimnames = list(table_rows, table_columns))
# convert matrix to list so that one can use as.data.frame's fix.empty.names=F:
df <- as.data.frame(setNames(lapply(1:ncol(m), function(x) m[, x]), colnames(m)), check.names=F, fix.empty.names = F)
write.xlsx(df, tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx"))
shell.exec(tf)
```

Comment: This did work, but i fixed it by using `table <- as.data.frame(table, optional = TRUE)` as a result of Gregors comment. I did change the `""` to `" "` (with a space in between) so that these columns are not renamed to `V2` etc.

Comment: @Icipher However, that only affects the `check.names`, not `fix.empty.names`. Renaming the column names seems a bit more hackish to me. ;)

Comment: `fix.empty.names` however does not work when I include it in `table <- as.data.frame(table, optional = TRUE, fix.empty.names = FALSE)`. Columns are named `V2` etc in this case.

Comment: @Icipher huh, you are right, `fix.empty.names` seems to be available only for `as.data.frame.list`, not for the matrix method. That's odd...